# Variable type 'color' doesn't work when using processing 3.5.3 in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, processing, processing-ide

I am just starting to learn image processing and I am using Processing 3.5.3. As the IDE in Processing was not too good with auto-completion, I decided to write the code in my Intellij with the rest of my project.

I am following a tutorial online and I am unable to use the variable type color (e.g. `color c = frog.get(x,y);` )

When I use the same code in Processing IDE it works perfectly fine, but Intellij complains `"Cannot resolve symbol"`. I am not sure why is that and I couldn't find anything online.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `color` type is part of the magic that the Processing Editor gives you. You can't use it in other editors.

Behind the scenes, the `color` type is actually an `int` value. So anywhere you see a line like this:

```
color c = color(32, 64, 128);
```

You can use an `int` instead:

```
int c = color(32, 64, 128);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. At first, I thought I needed to add some imports I didn't know about. I have used that instead and all works fine.